# how to find z where $\frac{z+i}{z-3i}$ is purely imaginary?

Tags: complex-analysis

how to find z where $\frac{z+i}{z-3i}$ is purely imaginary?

Please help me with this qn.

Comment: Shouldn't z be part of an equation or function to solve somehow?

Comment: Have you tried ... anything?

Answer (score 5):

Let $z=a+ib$

$$\frac{z+i}{z-3i}=\frac{a+i(b+1)}{a+i(b-3)}=\frac{[a+i(b+1)][a-i(b-3)]}{a^2+(b-3)^2}$$

So, we need $\displaystyle a^2+(b-3)(b+1)=0\iff a^2+(b-1)^2=2^2$

Geometrically speaking, $z$ represents any point on a circle centered at $(0,1)$ with radius $=2$ unit

Comment: I need two equation to solve for a and b. Can I equate the imaginary part as b?

Comment: I don't think that there is enough information given in the problen to find specific a and b. The condition given in the problem is satisfied by any pair of $ (a, b) $ which satisfies the equation given by Lab

Comment: I'm with you up to the point where you completed the square:  I believe your circle should be centered on (0,1) with a radius of 2 ...  [Then my points _do_ fit on your circle.]

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Downvoter, please pinpoint the mistake here.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try substituting $z =a + b i$ for real $a,b$. Then simplify and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to express this:  we want to arrange that

$$ \frac{z+i}{z-3i} \ = \ bi \  \ \Rightarrow  \ \ z + i \ = \ (z - 3i) \ (bi) \ \  [z \ \neq \ 3i ]  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ z \ = \ z \cdot bi \ + \ 3b \ - \ i \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z \ (1 - bi) \  = \ 3b \ - \ i $$

$$ \Rightarrow z \ = \ \frac{3b \ - \ i }{1 \ - \ bi} \ = \ \frac{(3b \ - \ i) \ (1 \ + \ bi) }{1 + b^2} \ = \ \left( \frac{4b}{1 + b^2} \right) \ + \ i \ \left( \frac{3b^2 - 1 }{1 + b^2} \right) \ . $$

As others here have pointed out, there is no unique solution, but an infinite number of permissible choices for real $ \ b \ $ which give us complex numbers $ \ z \ $ that satisfy the equation.  (And we see that $ \ 3i \ $ , which we disallowed earlier, is *not* one of those numbers.  We may choose to omit $ \ b \ = \ 0 \ $ , which works in the equation, but gives us a ratio of zero, which is not considered "pure imaginary".)

[I'm sorry to have deleted and undeleted this post more than once -- it turns out I did the calculation correctly the second time, then did my *check* incorrectly...]

EDIT:  this appears to give an interesting "parameterization" of **lab bhattacharjee**'s circle, which I've illustrated below.  It also becomes clear why $ \ z \ = \ 3i \ $ is excluded in the ratio equation.

[image]